# A person suffering from many phobias

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the term which can be used to describe a person who is suffering from many phobias? I searched about this on Google but found nothing useful.

Comment: `a term which can be used to describe a person who is suffering from many phobias?` "Normal" was the first word that I thought of. :p

Comment: Is there an overall category to the phobias?  If they're all health-related **hypochondriac** would fit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The condition is called **polyphobia**:

> An abnormal fear of many things; a condition marked by the **presence of many phobias**.

([The American Heritage® Stedman's Medical Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/polyphobia))

The person suffering from polyphobia is **polyphobic**:

> Many phobic individuals have more than one phobia and hence are **polyphobic**.

([The Encyclopedia of Phobias, Fears, and Anxieties, Third Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=E2imSyZZDh0C&pg=PA390&dq=polyphobic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCzfiVuKnJAhULPBQKHQsiAQQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 390)

Comment: It's a good word and certainly a good definition, but I think Ricky is more on the mark. "A fear of many things" is not precisely a suffering of many phobias in my opinion. But +1 anyway :)

Comment: @DogLover I agree with you. I have accepted Ricky's answer, but this answer is also useful. +1 :) Thanks!

Comment: Well, personally, @Arjun, I prefer A.P.'s answer now that I've seen it. It sounds more elegant, to my ear at least. I'm only saying this because I have to be scrupulously objective at all times to compensate for my arrogance, which, of course, stems from my megalomania. But you already knew that.

Comment: I personally prefer "polyphobia" or "polyphobic", because it combines two *Greek* roots: [πολύς "many, much"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly) and [φόβος "fear"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobia), whereas "multiphobia" combines a *Latin* root multum "many" with a *Greek* one. This offends my delicate etymological sensibilities ;-)

Comment: I thought "polyphobia" was a fear of parrots.

Comment: @GregoryJ.Puleo -- Darn, you beat me to it!

Comment: "Panphobic" could fit similarly. "a state in which a patient fears everything or nothing, where anxiety...only becomes fixed for an instant at a time, passing from one object to another"

Comment: Panphobia (omniphobia, pantophobia, or panophobia) is a groundless fear of everything, I think: https://books.google.com/books?id=E2imSyZZDh0C&pg=PA374&dq=panphobia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsg52k-qrJAhVGECwKHRoJAgQQ6AEIMjAE#v=onepage&q&f=false Perhaps a person with a serious case of polyphobia could be described as "panphobic", I'm not sure.

Answer (score 13):

**multiphobic**

A person suffering from a number of phobias.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multiphobic

Comment: Mixing Latin and Greek roots? Yuck.

Comment: @200_success: I agree. The other one's better. I have already said so. What do you want me to do, puke?

Comment: Oh, I see your comment there now. You may re-swallow your puke.  =)

Comment: @200_success: I agree with your overall sentiment, but of course there are still a fair amount of [hybrid words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word) that have become firmly established in the English lexicon, even some *phobia* terms like *claustrophobia*. Puking whenever you encounter any of these these seems like it would be quite inconvenient! So we may have to learn to live with them.

Answer (score 6):

While the other phrases are more clinically correct, if I were to discuss such a person in daily conversation, I might say that they are **Neurotic**, as in

> The man was neurotic; Everything alarmed him to some degree. He spent most of his life trying to escape his fears.

Answer (score 1):

**'Fraidy-cat** is more colloquial. It refers to a very fearful person, afraid of everything, easily startled.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fraidy+cat - also as suggested here, you might use **coward**.

Answer (score -1):

> Phobophobia can also be defined as the fear of phobias or fear of
>   developing a phobia. Phobophobia is related to anxiety disorders and
>   panic attacks directly linked to other types of phobias, such as
>   agoraphobia.

[Phobophobia - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobophobia)

Comment: What a terrifying answer.

Comment: That's interesting but I don't see how it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

### Polyphobic

This is the name for a person who suffers from many phobias, formed from the prefix for many (poly) + phobic =polyphobic

Comment: Hey stan! Welcome to EL&U stack exchange. You can improve the credibility of this answer by adding a dictionary definition from a reputable source.

Answer (score -3):

***Agoraphobia*** covers a lot of different phobic problems.

Strictly it is 'fear of open spaces', but tends to be used to describe anxiety states where the sufferer perceives the environment around them to be threatening.